# onDraw() efficient design for a custom view

Tags: android

I have a custom view that represents simple gameboard with several tiles. I have a 2-d array that stores the currently displayed image (0 for no image) for a tile.

Currently within my `onDraw()` method I loop through the array and display the images for the tiles. However the only time I invoke `invalidate()` without any args is when I reset the board. In all other places I only invoke an `invalidate(Rect)` for the required tile that needs to be updated.

Is this above implementation of `onDraw()` in-efficiently drawing the view? If so what would be a better way to do this? (also does invoking invalidate(Rect) guarantee updating only the 'Rect' region OR is this just a recommendation to Android that may be ignored?).

Appreciate any clarifications with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this above implementation of `onDraw()` in-efficiently drawing the view?

It is good enough. Otherwise you'd like to learn OpenGL to make use of hardware acceleration in your drawings, but all of this depends on if your tiles are changing every frame or how many tiles you have.

> also does invoking invalidate(Rect) guarantee updating only the 'Rect' region OR is this just a recommendation to Android that may be ignored?

It updates the `Rect` area, infact Romain Guy uses `invalidate(Rect)` for the default home launcher application in order to not update the whole screen everytime the home screen needs an update.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that even though my onDraw() loops through all the tiles and calls drawBitmap() on each, Android would only draw the one that was actually marked dirty (i.e. invalidated)?

Comment: Are you saying we would need to determine the current bounds (with getClipBounds()) determine which tiles fit in those bounds and redraw those (hmm.. need to see how to determine which tiles then)?

Comment: Thanks. Looking into it now. Any suggestions on how to efficiently determine which tiles fall within the invalidated rect?

Comment: @source.rar: Hm, I was thinking. It may be like when your invalidating through a `Rect`, all `drawBitmap()` calls which don't fall in the dirty specified area are automatically ignored, however, I'm not sure.

Comment: Romain Guy mentions that the "framework is smart enough to avoid drawing anything that falls outside of this region". So I guess there's no need to determine that myself.

Comment: @source.rar: Yeah, that was what I thought too! Thanks for responding anyway!